# Connecting to Teradata with R through DBI and ODBC

Tags: r, odbc, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, r-dbi

I connect to Teradata using the *Teradata SQL Assistant*. The connection parameters consist of a server address and a driver (server info changed for privacy reasons), as shown below:

```
Name: my_teradata_connection
Teradata Server Info: 00.11.22.333
Data Source: Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
UID: My_User_ID
PWD: My_PWD
```

I am trying to use R to connect to Teradata, using the `DBI` and `odbc` packages.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "[your driver's name]",
                      Host   = "[your server's path]",
                      DBCName = "[IP Address or Alias]"
                      UID    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                      PWD    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))
```

It seems obvious the `Driver` should be `Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20`. But where do I put the `Teradata Server Info` that we'll say is  `00.11.22.333`? Should it populate the `Host` or the `DBCName` arguments? And whichever one it does not populate, what will go there?

Comment: `DBCName` is either an IP-address (i.e. `00.11.22.333`) or the network name of your Teradata system (resolved by DNS/etc. to a list of IP-addresses of all Teradata nodes)

Comment: @dnoeth when I connect using the _Teradata SQL Assistant_ I can't recall ever being asked for a `Host   = "[your server's path]"`. Is this needed? Or can I discard that argument?

Comment: I assume this is for local DBMSes, e.g. Access, thus not needed

Comment: Also note that Teradata offers a *Teradata SQL Driver for R* and also *Teradata R package* analytic library, which don't depend on ODBC. See https://downloads.teradata.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, in most DB-APIs including ODBC connections *server* and *host* are synonymous keywords where you will not see both together but only one (of course with exceptions). Specifically, per `odbc` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/odbc.pdf), `dbConnect` maintains the *optional* `server` argument:

```
dbConnect(
     drv,
     dsn = NULL,
     ...,
     timezone = "UTC",
     timezone_out = "UTC",
     encoding = "",
     bigint = c("integer64", "integer", "numeric", "character"),
     timeout = 10,
     driver = NULL,
     server = NULL,
     database = NULL,
     uid = NULL,
     pwd = NULL,
     dbms.name = NULL,
     .connection_string = NULL
)
```

However, the `...` indicates additional ODBC driver keywords that would be specific to corresponding driver, here being Terdata ODBC driver.

> ...          Additional ODBC keywords, these will be joined with the other arguments to
>   form the final connection string

---

And from ODBC Driver for Teradata 16.20 [documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/pk_W2JQRhJlg28QI7p0n8Q/_f_rmCzerdVLUhkL367NDw), `Driver` and `DBCName` are **required** keywords.`DBCName` appears to be synonymous to *server* or *host* given the IP address or alias indication.

> DBCName = `<IP-addr-or-alias>`

```
| Keyword/Synonym                                             | Description                                                                             |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Driver=<driver-path>                                        | [Required] The full path to the ODBC Driver for Teradata shared objects…                |
| Description=<data-source-desc>                              | [Optional] Descriptive text about the data source.                                      |
| DBCName=<IP-addr-or-alias>                                  | [Required] The IP address or FQDN (fully qualified domain name) of the Teradata server… |
| Username=<name> or UID=<name>                               | [Optional] The default username for logging onto a Teradata server system.              |
| Password=<password>                                         | [Optional] The password required for the default Username.                              |
| DefaultDatabase=<database-name> Or Database=<database-name> | [Optional] The default database associated with the specified data source…              |
| UPTMode                                                     | Default = NOTSET…                                                                       |
```

---

Therefore in R, use the `DBCName` only. Below adds in the optional `Database` keyword.

```
# KEYWORD APPROACH
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20",
                      DBCName  = "00.11.22.333",
                      Database = "myDatabase",
                      UID      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                      PWD      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))

# CONNECTION STRING APPROACH
con_str = "Driver={Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20};DBCName=00.11.22.333;Database=myDatabase;"

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      .connection_string = con_str,
                      UID = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                      PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
```